# flash as3 delete all characters in a url string before a certain path

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, substring

I am pulling in a URL from an XML file which leads with the domain name (http://site.com/) followed by the path to a series of images (images/uploads/file.jpg).

I need to have a relative path to the files, without the domain name. Previously, I was just using this code:

```
file = myXML.project.fileURL.substring(26)
```

To chop off the unwanted 26 characters from the string, but since I'll be going back and forth between local, staging, and live environments, I need to find a more dynamic way of doing things - basically to get rid of everything before "images/" in the URL. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regEx is the best way for sure.

Test data that I used:

```
        var asdf:String = "http://site.com/images/uploads/file.jpg";
        var fdsa:String = "http://www.site.com/images/uploads/file.jpg";
        var anot:String = "ftp://asfd.werqsvxc.qewoihdsv.asuvxc.fwhfrew/images/asdf/asdf.afds";

        var myregTest:RegExp = /^(\w+:\/\/)?((\w+\.){0,999})?(\w+)?\//;

        fdsa = fdsa.replace(myregTest, " ");
        asdf = asdf.replace(myregTest, " ");
        anot = anot.replace(myregTest, " ");
```

Output for the 3 strings I tested.

```
images/uploads/file.jpg
images/uploads/file.jpg
images/asdf/asdf.afds
```

Oh the {0,999} in the middle is so it can repeat the foo.bar.foo.bar.foo.bar etc as many times as it needs. There is a better way to let it loop but I can't remember off the top of my head.

So it is limited to 998 dot's basically. (which is absurd for a URL I know) There is a better way.

Hope this helps a little.

Edit: edited to remove the leading '/' to make it exactly like what you said you needed.

Comment: man - regexes just look like such nonsense to me. Glad you understand this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Do a combination of split, splice, join:

```
var s:String = "http://test.local/images/something.jpg";

var output:String = s.split('/').splice(3).join("/");

trace(output);
```

[split](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#split%28%29): explodes your string in parts

[splice](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Array.html#splice%28%29): extract a sub part of the array

[join](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Array.html#join%28%29):re-attach parts of the array into a new string